# Submerged inflow doesn't add to fluid volume

Tags: fluid-simulation

So if you position your inflow inside the fluid, or where it's going to be submerged after a while, it stops producing fluid volume. Funnily enough, I've encountered the problem with both Blender fluid sim and Flip Fluids. Anyone knows what's going on an how to solve the issue?

Comment: Look at the [constrain fluid velocity](https://github.com/rlguy/Blender-FLIP-Fluids/wiki/Inflow-Object-Settings#inflow-velocity) "_Enabling this option will allow an inflow to push around fluid when submerged and can also be used to fill up a tank when submerged_"

Comment: Hey, you're right, had not seen that one. One point for FF. Many thanks

Comment: Has this opting been removed? Should it be in the inflow object physics properties?
I can't find it in Blender 2.92.